# How can I reduce the bounciness of a floor?

Tags: joists, structural, noise

My apartment is on the second floor of a low-rise building. There are no units directly under it; the apartment sits above the open-air garage.

I feel basically everything that my next door neighbors (on the same floor) do in this building, which shakes my entire 1BR apartment floor and makes any chair, bed or couch you are sitting on wobble, as if somebody's constantly shaking it. The intensity of the impact sometimes makes other stuff in the apartment shake and rattle, but most of the time it's just a low frequency shaking that's too annoying to ignore. Neighbors are both wild kids running around, and big people that make big noises and stomp everywhere. Opening doors, footsteps, all of it, sends endless tremors that shake wherever you go. It's getting to be incredibly annoying and increasingly unlivable.

From the ground floor (garage) looking up, you can see large beams covered in stucco.

My question is not specifics, but a general question. Is there a way of strapping these joists to help utterly stiffen my floor and absorb all neighbor's impacts, so I don't feel like I'm on a boat or in a perpetual earthquake? It would have to absorb the impact of my (big) stomping neighbors.

Comment: My advise is to move. It is obvious the floor joists are not substantial enough to support the load, thus are flexing under normal use. There is no DIY remedy that I would recommend for a rental unit.

Comment: This question is basically a complete redo of this other one: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/26923/what-economical-ways-exist-to-dampen-floor-vibration-on-top-floor-apartment

Comment: If you build the minimum required by code, it's easy to get a floor that is bouncy, especially if spans are long. 

If you don't move, you will eventually get used to it.

Comment: I wonder if the two common questions are from the pair of neighbors.